# Do we know anything about magical history before Harry?

Tags: harry-potter

Are there any other resources describing how the world of magic was before Harry was born and how Voldemort came to power the first time. Even articles about Dumbledore would be genuinely interesting. Maybe any article on Pottermore or any other article.

Even fanfiction is welcomed. (Articles have to be remarkably interesting and shouldn't talk about magic creatures, Quidditch or a magic singer, like the last boring article on pottermore). I really enjoyed *Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince* since it contained a lot of memories from the past.

Comment: "Remarkably interesting" is completely subjective and this question is primarily opinion-based. I'm voting to close, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, plenty.**

J.K. Rowling has discussed the history of the magical world in plenty of places, including:

- **Supplementary books.** *Quidditch through the Ages*, *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* and *The Tales of Beedle the Bard*, three books written in an in-universe style that were published by J.K. Rowling for Comic Relief.

  *Quidditch* is mostly the history of the sport, while *Beasts* contains discussion of the history of magical zoology. Fragments in *Tales*, based on Dumbledore’s commentary.
- **Interviews**, usually as fragments or comments on another question. Complete transcripts of most of her interviews are on [Accio Quote](http://www.accio-quote.org).
- **Pottermore updates**, usually in the “New from J.K. Rowling” sections. Most of this is based upon characters, objects or places in the story, but there’s some interesting stuff there.
- **Famous Wizard cards.** Some of the tie-in video games feature Famous Wizard cards, analogous to the chocolate frog cards in the books. For some of the games, J.K. Rowling wrote the descriptions, so these are considered canon. The HP Lexicon has a [complete list of cards](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/card_wizards.html).

A complete list of all of these articles and resources is almost certainly beyond the scope of this site, but this should give you an idea of where you might get started.

As for Voldemort’s history in particular, interviews and Pottermore are probably your best bet, although I expect to see more about Voldemort in future Pottermore updates.

Asking for recommendations for opinion-based or discussion articles, or good fanfiction that explores magical history, is likely to get closed on the main site, but one of the HP regulars in the [site chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/198/mos-eisley) might be able to suggest something.

Comment: *A complete list of all of these articles and resources is almost certainly beyond the scope of this site* I kind of did that [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114611/55866)

Answer (score 0):

If you read books, dumbledore explained how voldemort comes to power before harry was born in Half Blood prince,and dumbledores history is explaind in Deathly hallows(about his dreams when he was young, friendship with grindelwald, family background etc.).
The books contains nearly everything about history of voldemort and dumbledore.

Comment: I think nearly everything is an overstatement.