# What other Harry Potter related writings has Rowling written?

Tags: harry-potter, canon, jk-rowling

Which Harry Potter related writings has J K Rowling written (not counting the seven main books)?

I'm ideally looking for writings set in the Harry Potter world, not writings about the books. (i.e. *The Tales of Beedle the Bard* is good; an essay about her experiences with the fandom is not) I'm also only looking for writings that were published at one point in some form or another (be it online, in print, or even for a now defunct official fan club).

Comment: Do you want just published works or all writings credited to her?

Comment: Related: [Did the Harry Potter supplemental books contain clues relating to the main storyline?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6795/21267) and [Reading order for Harry Potter auxilary books?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/76253/21267) and [Are there any discrepancies between HP1-HP7 and supplementary books?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46092/21267)

Comment: @Mooz Maybe the reading order one, I don't know about the others.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Note: Many smaller tidbits ([example](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430144610/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=113)) are not mentioned in this list. Lots of these can be found on [Accio-Quote](http://www.accio-quote.org)

### Companion books

- Quidditch Through The Ages
- Fantastic Beasts And Where To Find Them <sub>(both the 2001 and 2017 editions)</sub>
- The Tales of Beedle the Bard
- [Book of Spells](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/1w7034/miranda_goshawks_book_of_spells_pdf/) (stories and descriptions were written by Rowling)
- [Book of Potions](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/4s4cgp/zygmunt_budges_book_of_potions_pdf/) (stories and descriptions were written by Rowling)

### Published on [the old jkrowling.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430090537/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en) <sub><sup><sub><sup>(2004-2012)</sup></sub></sup></sub>

- [various early drafts/sketches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQqlQ.jpg) of the books
- [Rumor tabloids](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/about/sources/jkr.com/jkr-com-rumours.html#ads)
- [Wizard of the Month](https://web.archive.org/web/20110607100701/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/wotm.cfm)
- FAQ's with long answers ([Thestrals](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430144651/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=21), [Mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430144654/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=22), [Mark Evans](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430144617/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=49), [half-blood](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430150208/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=58), [Marauder's Map](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430145110/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=65), [technology](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430145124/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=81), [Neville](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430145033/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=84), [communication](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430144627/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=99), [Flitwick](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430144704/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=95), [Veritaserum](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430145127/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=105), [Avada Kedavra](https://web.archive.org/web/20110430090622/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=122), [Secret keepers](https://web.archive.org/web/20110607102752/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_poll.cfm))
- [Nearly Headless Nick's ballad](https://web.archive.org/web/20110623034857/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=11)
- W.O.M.B.A.T. [Grade 1](https://beta.hp-lexicon.org/sources/other-canon/jkr/jkr-w1), [Grade 2](https://beta.hp-lexicon.org/sources/other-canon/jkr/jkr-w2/), [Grade 3](https://beta.hp-lexicon.org/sources/other-canon/jkr/jkr-w3/), [Answers](https://pastebin.com/raw/wx27jBS2)
- [Weasley family tree](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/images/jkr/weasleyfamilytree-website.jpg)
- Other small bits of writing ([Crookshanks](https://web.archive.org/web/20110623034902/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=10), [Dudley](https://web.archive.org/web/20110623034847/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=26), [Weasleys](https://web.archive.org/web/20110607110001/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=7), [Owls](https://web.archive.org/web/20110607112746/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=20), [Spells](https://web.archive.org/web/20110607111700/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=24), [Squibs](https://web.archive.org/web/20110607100056/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/extrastuff_view.cfm?id=19))
- [Various tidbits](http://www.accio-quote.org/jkrwebsite.html) (in the style which she would later do on twitter)

### Published on the new jkrowling.com (Technically there was a site in-between, but we won't talk about it.) <sub><sup><sub><sup>(2016-present)</sup></sub></sup></sub>

- [FAQ](https://jkrowling.com/welcome-to-my-new-website/)
- [Drafts](https://jkrowling.com/wp-content/themes/jkrowling/assets/images/script.png)
- [Notes](https://jkrowling.com/wp-content/themes/jkrowling/assets/images/paper-notes-and-bracelet.png)
- [Rumors](https://www.jkrowling.com/opinion-category-rumours/)
- [Drawings](https://jkrowling.com/wp-content/themes/jkrowling/assets/images/painting.png)

### Published on the old Pottermore <sub><sup><sub><sup>(2011-2015)</sup></sub></sup></sub>

- Quizzes ([Sorting](https://guide-to-pottermore-items.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_29.html), [Wand](https://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Ollivanders_Bespoke_Wand_Selector))
- 'New Writing from J.K. Rowling' ([The Quill of Acceptance and The Book of Admittance](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-quill-of-acceptance-and-the-book-of-admittance). [Number Four, Privet Drive](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/number-four-privet-drive), [Measurements](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/measurements), [Vernon & Petunia Dursley](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vernon-and-petunia-dursley), [Ghost Plots](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ghost-plots), [Clothing](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/clothing), [Mr Ollivander](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/mr-ollivander), [Wand Woods](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-woods), [Wand Lengths & Flexibility](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-lengths-and-flexibilit), [Wand Cores](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wand-cores), [Hogwarts Express](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express), [Platform Nine and Three-Quartures](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/platform-nine-and-three-quarters), [Toads](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/toads), [Professor McGonagall](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-mcgonagall), [Hatstall](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hatstall), [Sorting Hat](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-sorting-hat), [Hufflepuff Common Room](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hufflepuff-common-room), [Familiars](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/familiars), [Hogwarts School Subjects](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-school-subjects), [The Original Forty](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-original-forty), [Mirror of Erised](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-mirror-of-erised), [Nicolas Flamel](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/nicolas-flamel), [Professor Quirrell](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-quirrell), [The Philosopher's Stone](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-philosophers-stone), [Technology](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/technology), [Floo Powder](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/floo-powder), [Celestina Warbeck](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/celestina-warbeck), [The Malfoy Family](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-malfoy-family), [King's Cross Station](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/kings-cross-station), [Pure-blood](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pure-blood), [Gilderoy Lockhart](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/gilderoy-lockhart), [Peeves](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/peeves), [Hogwarts Ghosts](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-ghosts), [Draco Malfoy](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/draco-malfoy), [The Polyjuice Potion](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/polyjuice-potion), [Ghosts](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ghosts), [Chamber of Secrets](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/chamber-of-secrets), [The Sword of Gryffindor](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-sword-of-gryffindor), [Marge Dursley](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/marge-dursley), [The Knight Bus](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-knight-bus), [Sir Cadogan](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/sir-cadogan), [Professor Kettleburn](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/professor-kettleburn), [Boggart](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/boggart), [Hogwarts Portraits](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/hogwarts-portraits), [The Marauder's Map](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-marauders-map), [Gobstones](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/gobstones), [Dementors and Chocolate](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/dementors-and-chocolate), [Firebolt](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/firebolt), [Secret Keeper](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/secret-keeper), [Werewolves](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves), [Time-Turner](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/time-turner), [Patronus Charm](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/patronus-charm),  [Remus Lupin](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/remus-lupin), [The Floo Network](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-floo-network), [Portkeys](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/portkeys), [Colours](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/colours), [History of the Quidditch World Cup, 
  Quidditch World Cup (1990-2014)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/history-of-the-quidditch-world-cup), [Scottish Rugby](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/scottish-rugby), [Beauxbatons Academy of Magic](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/beauxbatons-academy-of-magic), [Durmstrang Institute](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/durmstrang-institute), [Daily Prophet](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-daily-prophet), [The Great Lake](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-great-lake), [Owls](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/owls), [Pensieve](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/pensieve),  [Illness and Disability](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/illness-and-disability), [Ministers of Magic](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ministers-for-magic), [Thestrals](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/thestrals), [Dolaras Umbridge](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/dolores-umbridge), [Sybill Trelawney](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/sybill-trelawney), [Naming Seers](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/naming-seers), [Azkaban](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/azkaban), [Cokeworth](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/cokeworth), [Florean Fortescue](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/florean-fortescue), [The Leaky Cauldron](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-leaky-cauldron), [Cauldrons](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/cauldrons), [Potions](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/potions), [Vampires](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/vampires), [Inferi](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/inferi), [Order of Merlin](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/order-of-merlin), [Extension Charms](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/extension-charms), [Alchemy](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/alchemy))
- [House welcome messages](https://guide-to-pottermore-items.blogspot.com/p/houses-welcoming-messages.html)
- Book extracts ([Curses and Counter-Curses](https://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Curses_and_Counter-Curses#Extract), [The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 1](https://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/The_Standard_Book_of_Spells,_Grade_1#New_from_J.K._Rowling), 
  [A Beginner's Guide to Transfiguration](https://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Guide_to_Transfiguration#New_from_J.K._Rowling), [One Thousand Magical Herbs and Fungi](https://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/One_Thousand_Magical_Herbs_and_Fungi#New_from_J.K._Rowling), [The Dark Forces: A Guide to Self-Protection](https://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dark_Forces:_A_Guide_to_Self-Protection#New_from_J.K._Rowling), [Book of Spells](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKJHQDN4n6Y), [Book of Potions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FpS1KCgK7g), [other spell books](https://beta.hp-lexicon.org/sources/other-canon/pm/pmsb))
- [Quidditch World Cup daily prophet articles](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/quidditch-world-cup-2014-daily-prophet-reports) (Disastrous Opening Ceremony Leads to Questions about Quidditch World Cup Security, Norway v Ivory Coast, Nigeria v Fiji, Brazil v Haiti, USA v Jamaica, Liechtenstein v Chad, Bulgaria v New Zealand, Japan v Poland, Wales v Germany, Brazil v Wales, Bulgaria v Norway, USA v Liechtenstein, Late Breaking News, Hans the Augery, Japan v Nigeria, Place your Bets with Ludo Bagman, USA v Brazil, Bulgaria v Japan, Dumbledore's Army Reunites at the Quidditch World Cup, [Quidditch World Cup Final](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/quidditch-world-cup-final-live-report))

### Published on [the new Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com) <sub><sup><sub><sup>(2015-present)</sup></sub></sup></sub>

- [The Potter Family](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-potter-family)
- Wizarding Schools ([Wizarding Schools](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/wizarding-schools), [Castelobruxo](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/castelobruxo), [Mahoutokoro](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/mahoutokoro), [Uagadou](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/uagadou))
- Magic in North America ([History of Magic in North America](https://www.pottermore.com/collection-episodic/history-of-magic-in-north-america-en), [Ilvermorny School of Witchcraft and Wizardry](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/ilvermorny), [The Magical Congress of the United States of America (MACUSA)](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/macusa))
- [Illvermorny Sorting Quiz](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/4qedhl/all_ilvermorny_sorting_quiz_questions/)
- [Patronus test](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/53yufn/pottermore_patronus_test_all_possible_questions/)
- Fact files ([Dolores Umbridge](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/dolores-umbridge), [Minerva McGonagall](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/minerva-mcgonagall), [Garrick Ollivander](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/garrick-ollivander), [Quirinus Quirrell](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/quirinus-quirrell), [Remus Lupin](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/remus-lupin), [Sybill Trelawney](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/sybill-trelawney), [Horace Slughorn](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/horace-slughorn))

### Published in Pottermore Presents <sub><sup><sub><sup>(2016)</sup></sub></sup></sub>

- Animagi
- Horace Slughorn

### Online Chats

- [First Barnes & Nobles](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0399-barnesandnoble.html)
- [Second Barnes & Nobles](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0999-barnesnoble-staff.htm)
- [First Scholastic](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0200-scholastic-chat.htm)
- [Second Scholastic](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-scholastic-chat.htm)
- [AOL](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-aol-chat.htm)
- [Third Barnes & Nobles](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-livechat-barnesnoble.html)
- [BBC](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-bbc-rednose.htm)
- [Comic Relief](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-comicrelief-staff.htm)
- [World Book Day](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm)
- [cBBC Newsround](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-bbc-mzimba.htm)
- [Bloomsbury](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)

### Others

- [The Famous Wizard Cards](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizards/card_wizards.html) (written by JKR for the video games) See also [this image](https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/harrypotter/images/2/28/Timeline_of_the_Wizarding_World.png/revision/latest?cb=20150904020044&format=original).
- [The Daily Prophet newsletters](https://beta.hp-lexicon.org/sources/other-canon/dp/) (Written for Bloomsbury's Official Harry Potter Fan Club)
- [The Black Family Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVIhB.jpg) (created for a charity auction)
- [The Harry Potter Prequel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUJHm.png) (written for a charity auction)
- [Random tidbits](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121097/is-there-a-complete-list-of-jk-rowlings-harry-potter-tweets) on [twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling)
- [Various drawings and sketches](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzktoPZRvTdaRkRrY1l1anQ1ODQ)
- The original screenplays for the upcoming Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them films (it is unknown how much of the final product will be based on Rowling's work, and whether she wrote them as book canon or as movie canon)
- The LEGO Batman Movie ([Rowling wrote some of Voldemort's character and dialogue](https://ew.com/movies/2017/02/13/lego-batman-director-burning-questions-ending/))

### Somewhat Canon works not written by Rowling:

- Interviews ([Herald](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1997/0697-herald-johnstone.html), [Electronic Telegraph](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1998/0798-telegraph-bertodano.html), [Herald](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1998/1298-herald-simpson.html), [Scotland on Sunday](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0199-scotlandsunday-goring.html), [Guardian Unlimited](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0299-guardian-carey.htm), [Amazon](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0099-amazon-staff.htm), [Salon](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0399-salon-weir.htm), [School Library Journal](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0999-slj-feldman.htm), [Family Education](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0999-familyeducation-abel.htm), [Connection](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-connectiontransc.html), [Star Ledger](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-starledger-garrity2.html), [Boston Globe](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-bostonglobe-loer.html), [NPR Radio](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-pressclubtransc.htm), [Diane Rehm Show](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1299-wamu-rehm.htm), [Chicago Sun Times](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-chictimes-tucker.html), [Orange County Register](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-orangecounty-takahama.html), [Sans Francisco Chronicle](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1099-sfchronicle-chonin.html), [People](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/1299-people.html), [Associated Press](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0300-ap.html), [London Times](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0600-times-treneman.html), [Daily Telegraph](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-dailytelegraph-demetriou.htm), [CBBC Newsround](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-cbbc-mzimba.htm), [Bloomsbury Press](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-bloomsbury-fry.html), [Guardian Unlimited](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-guardian-hattenstone.htm), [The Herald](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0708-herald-johnstone.html), [South West News Service](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-swns-alfie.htm) [CBCNewsWorld](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0700-hottype-solomon.htm), [Telling Tales](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0439314550), [Entertainment Weekly](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/0900-ew-jensen.htm), [eToys.com](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/fall00-etoys.html), [Larry King Live](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-cnn-larryking.htm), [Canadian Press](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-canadianpress-moore.htm), [Time Magazine](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1000-time-staff.htm), [Maclean's](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1100-macleans-bethune.html), [Cinescape](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1100-cinescape-garcia2.htm), [Reader's Digest](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2000/1200-readersdigest-boquet.htm), [Raincoast Books](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-raincoast-interview.html), [Blue Peter](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-bluepeter.htm), [Houston Chronicle](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/0301-houston-thomas.html), [Sydney Morning Herald](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/1001-sydney-renton.htm), [Candis Magazine](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/1101-candis-renton.html), [Ananova](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/1201-ananova-staff.htm), [BBC](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2001/1201-bbc-hpandme.htm), [CBS News](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2002/1002-sixtymin-stahl.html), [Scotsman](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2002/1102-fraser-scotsman.html), [IGN](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2002/1102-ign.html), [CoS DVD](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2003/0302-newsround-mzimba.htm), [BBC Newsnight](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2003/0619-bbcnews-paxman.htm), [Royal Albert Hall](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2003/0626-alberthall-fry.htm), [Edinburgh Book Festival](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0804-ebf.htm), [PoA DVD](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/1104-poadvd.htm), [Leaky Cauldron part 1](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-1.htm) [2](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-2.htm) [3](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-tlc_mugglenet-anelli-3.htm), [ITV](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-edinburgh-ITVcubreporters.htm), [ITV Network](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-edinburgh-jones-official.html), [ITV](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-itv-coad.htm), [Time Magazine](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-time-grossman.htm), [Dateline NBC](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/0705-nbcdateline-couric.htm), [BBC Radio](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2005/1205-bbc-fry.html), [Tatler magazine](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0110-tatler-grieg.html), [Chanel Four Corporation](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0626-ch4-richardandjudy.html), [Press Conference](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0801-radiocity-pressconf.html), [Radio City Music Hall part 1](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0801-radiocityreading1.html) [2](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0802-radiocityreading2.html), [bigbadread.com](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0904-bigbadread.html), [Jonathon Ross](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0706-bbc-ross.html), [Scotsman](http://news.scotsman.com/topics.cfm?tid=3&id=1091272007), [Blue Peter](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0720-bluepeter.html), [USA Today](http://www.usatoday.com/life/books/news/2007-07-25-jk-rowling_N.htm), [Today Show part 1](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0726-today-vieira1.html) [2](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0726-today-vieira2.html), [Reuters](http://www.reuters.com/article/entertainmentNews/idUSN1537267520071015), [MTV.com](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1571977/20071015/), [MTV.com](http://www.mtv.com/news/articles/1572107/20071017/), [hollywood.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20071024104010/http://www.hollywood.com/feature/Harry_Potter_JK_Rowling_US_Book_Tour/4947899), [Times-Picayune](http://blog.nola.com/living/2007/10/new_orleans_students_give_rowl.html), [The Leaky Cauldron part 1](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/19/j-k-rowling-talks-marriage-writing-and-more-at-open-book-tour-stop-in-new-york-city) [2](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more) [3](http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/22/pottercast-122-it-s-saturday-night/), [Canadian Broadcasting Corporation](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1022-torontopressconf.html), [Canadian Press](https://www.thestar.com/entertainment/article/269527), [BBC News](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/entertainment/7072086.stm), [Pottercast part 1](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1217-pottercast-anelli.html) [2](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/1224-pottercast-anelli.html), [Time Magazine part 1](http://content.time.com/time/specials/2007/personoftheyear/article/0,28804,1690753_1695388_1695436,00.html) [2](http://www.time.com/time/specials/2007/personoftheyear/article/0,28804,1690753_1695388_1695569,00.html), [J.K. Rowling, A Year in the Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6-6zaa4NI4), [XLSemanal](http://www.snitchseeker.com/harry-potter-news/j-k-rowling-talks-cornelius-fudge-new-interview-53897/), [Lexicon book court case](https://web.archive.org/web/20110721204007/http://cyberlaw.stanford.edu/system/files/Trial+Transcript+Day+1.txt), [NBC Dateline](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/20001720/ns/dateline_nbc-harry_potter/t/harry-potter-final-chapter/), [Conversation with Steve Kloves](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoBPOZznSvY), [Scholastic](http://www.snitchseeker.com/harry-potter-news/jk-rowling-full-harry-potter-reading-club-webchat-discussion-transcript-now-available-91349/), [Wonderland](http://www.mugglenet.com/2014/02/the-truth-behind-the-j-k-rowling-wonderland-interview/))
- [Artwork from the old jkrowling.com](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/about/sources/jkr.com/jkr-com-wotm-pics.html)
- [Artwork from the old Pottermore](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0TGf4bxO8wBaUU3RTh5emE1YVE)
- [Pottermore content of the new Bloomsbury editions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj70d.jpg)
- The Harry Potter and the Cursed Child play by Jack Thorne (Rowling was a producer, and possibly had a little input to the story.)

Answer (score 17):

Wikipedia's [list for her publications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J._K._Rowling#Publications) is accurate:

> #### Related works
>
> - *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* (supplement to the Harry Potter series) (1 March 2001)
> - *Quidditch Through the Ages* (supplement to the Harry Potter series) (1 March 2001)
> - *The Tales of Beedle the Bard* (supplement to the Harry Potter series) (4 December 2008)
>
> #### Short stories
>
> - [Harry Potter prequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_prequel) (July 2008)

In addition to that, she writes the articles found on [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/), which not only adds background details to the Potterverse, but has also released information about events *after* the series. Not all content on the website is authored by her, however. For a more complete breakdown of her online and digital works, see [@ibid's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114611/31178).

She is also a regular [user of Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling), and [more than once has posted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bharry-potter%5D%20twitter%20is%3Aa) new Word of God canon through her tweets and not elsewhere.

Rowling has also been said to have written the *story* for the new Harry Potter play, [*Harry Potter and the Cursed Child*](http://www.harrypottertheplay.com/), but the story is also credited to Jack Thorne and John Tiffany. (Thanks to @JasonBaker for the reminder.)

She also wrote the screenplay, as mentioned by @DVK, for [*Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them_(film)), based loosely on the book (or more accurately, the character said to have written that book In-Universe, Newt Scamander).

> A spin-off/prequel of the Harry Potter film series and directed by David Yates, the film was written by Rowling as her screenwriting debut. It is the first installment of a trilogy. Rowling produced the film alongside David Heyman, Steve Kloves, and Lionel Wigram.

Comment: Some here speculated that post-reboot Pottermore isn't written by her. No proof either way, of course.

Comment: @DVK Without proof to the contrary, I'm happy to assume it's her. Although, considering her aptitude for contradicting herself, and her terrible maths ability, I'm not sure it would make a difference.

Comment: The quality seemed to have dropped significantly, and broadly. A somewhat subjective judgement, admittedly.

Comment: @DVK The two new pieces of writing marked as by her on the post-reboot Pottermore is by her, everything else there is Buzzfeed style top 10 lists and doesn't even resemble new canon.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from what is mentioned in @CreationEdge's answer, JK Rowling has recently completed a story that picks off from where the seventh book ends. This is called *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* and will be presented in the form of a play. You can check out more information [here](http://www.jkrowling.com/en_GB/#/news-events)

Comment: She didn't write the play. She was heavily involved with it, but it's not the same.

Comment: @ibid She didn't write the script, but she's credited as having written a story that the script was based on