# Which Harry Potter novel is the quote "Things are gonna get serious for you" from?

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, quotes

I read this quote from Harry Potter in the book or on the Internet, I don't remember. I think I read it 3-4 years ago. It was like

> Things are gonna get serious for you.

This quote was a play on his name.

This conversation took place between Sirius Black and someone (who was a Muggle, not a wizard).

I think he was riding his motorcycle as well.

It's a long task to go through all the novels, but I tried looking in those where Sirius appeared. However, I still couldn't find that quote.

Comment: Perhaps it was just a meme?

Comment: No. I don't think so. It was in the snippet of the story.

Comment: hmmm, does Sirius ever even talk to a muggle?

Comment: He usually doesn't, but he was in this one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The quote is from an untitled 2008 short story sold at a charity auction:

> 'Things'll be seriously black for you in a minute, you cheeky little--'

Quotes: [Harry Potter: The Prequel (Harry Potter 0.5)](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8933944-harry-potter) (Goodreads)

More information: [Harry Potter prequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_prequel) (Wikipedia)

Full transcript: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Harry_Potter_Prequel

Comment: Ah. So, it was this story. Thank you.

Comment: How did I not know this existed?

Comment: @terdon I'm uneasy about linking to the full transcript unless a free version authorized by the copyright holder is available.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I assumed that was authorized since it was so easy to find and openly shown in a well-known site, but feel very free to roll my edit back.

Comment: @EvSunWoodard - [Here's some more](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/114611/55866) that you probably didn't know existed.

Comment: @Gaultheria - A [*good quality* scan](http://imgur.com/a/9xAhN) of both sides of the postcard used to be freely available online from Waterstone's website. As far as I'm aware, there were never any official transcripts made.

Comment: @ibid - Thanks; since Waterstones made it publicly available, I agree that that settles it.

Comment: @terdon - I'm sorry.  You're right, and I should have considered the site.

Comment: @terdon - HP wiki has a *lot* of stuff which violate copyrights.